# How Do You Change an Existing File Via a NuGet Package Install?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Is it possible to change the contents of a file that exists via a NuGet package? Meaning, let's say you make a brand new MVC3 website. You want to install a NuGet package that will update the home page. Maybe change the welcome message and then change the layout to include some new View you've created and update the Home Controller to include a method to return your new View. How would this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you've installed the NuGet Package you can manually modify any files you want. Just edit them in VS (or with another editor). The only difference regarding NuGet packages is that your modified files won't be removed if you uninstall/update the package as changes are detected between the original package files and your files. There's going to be a mention of this is the logs.

Update:

NuGet has supports for modifying project files during a package installation through [.transform and .pp files](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations). But this has limitations, .transform files adds content to config files (they can't edit) while .pp files are for new source code files.

You can modify existing source code using [EnvDte CodeModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codemodel.aspx) in PowerShell (i.e. install.ps1). It's a bit more complex though.

Comment: That's not quite what I mean. I mean can you change a file via the install itself? For example, I've heard you can change the web.config within the NuGet package. Like, some directive or script, etc? I imagine that you could change any file via a script, but is there some typical way to do it? So when you install a package, you get some new files added, but some of your existing files get changed. Maybe change the contents of default.aspx, for example. Get my meaning yet?

Comment: got it now, I updated my answer above. In short nuget has baked in support for common simple scenarios in .pp/.transform files. Modifying existing code is not supported by NuGet and would be done through powershell scripts. I'd look at CodeModel but I couldn't find a simple example.

Comment: I saw stuff about having files - I think the pp ones - where you would leave variables instead of things like namespaces and it would grab it from the project file, etc., but how does the Entity Framework package, for example, add in the web.config nodes? Is it with a script?

Comment: They have a "Web.config.transform" file in the content of their package. Basically when NuGet installs the package, it merges the Web.config.transform file content with web.config. (and app.config.transform to app.config)

Answer (score 2):

If you open up the JQuery NuGet package in NuGet Package Explorer (or just unzip the package) and look at install.ps1 and common.ps1, then you can see an example where they automatically add a line to _references.js for JQuery so that the JQuery API will show up in IntelliSense.

But yes, it is a fairly complex process to automatically update code (especially code that people can edit).  The JQuery example involves using a regular expression to look for an existing reference before updating it, and all this does is add/update a one-line comment to a particular file in a known location (and it shouldn't break the build if it goes wrong, since it is just a comment).

I would love to see more examples and even a library of helper functions for things like the OP's request.

Here's one function from common.ps1:

```
function AddOrUpdate-Reference($scriptsFolderProjectItem, $fileNamePattern, $newFileName) {
    try {
        $referencesFileProjectItem = $scriptsFolderProjectItem.ProjectItems.Item("_references.js")
    }
    catch {
        # _references.js file not found
        return
    }

    if ($referencesFileProjectItem -eq $null) {
        # _references.js file not found
        return
    }

    $referencesFilePath = $referencesFileProjectItem.FileNames(1)
    $referencesTempFilePath = Join-Path $env:TEMP "_references.tmp.js"

    if ((Select-String $referencesFilePath -pattern $fileNamePattern).Length -eq 0) {
        # File has no existing matching reference line
        # Add the full reference line to the beginning of the file
        "/// <reference path=""$newFileName"" />" | Add-Content $referencesTempFilePath -Encoding UTF8
         Get-Content $referencesFilePath | Add-Content $referencesTempFilePath
    }
    else {
        # Loop through file and replace old file name with new file name
        Get-Content $referencesFilePath | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $fileNamePattern, $newFileName } > $referencesTempFilePath
    }

    # Copy over the new _references.js file
    Copy-Item $referencesTempFilePath $referencesFilePath -Force
    Remove-Item $referencesTempFilePath -Force
}
```

Comment: Thanks! A very "Hello, World!"-y example to get going on this kind of task.